# How can I use a Regular Expression to return a number of numbers at the end of a string of digits

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of digits that could vary in length and I want to return only the last 4 digits.  Would I use a positive lookback?  And use the **$** to anchor to?

Comment: Try using regexpal.com to check this.  Be warned that it has issues with lookback unless it is the first thing you put in your regex though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this regular expression `\d{4}$`

Comment: Yep - after your recommendations of regexpal.com I figured it out - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your string can be ANY length and you want to match the cases when you have 0 to 3 charaters you should use:

```
\d?\d?\d?\d?$
```

or, if the regex engine understands it:

```
\d{0-4}$
```